# How to prevent a Powershell script from prompting for user input

Tags: powershell

I am using Powersehll Core.

My PowerShell script is supposed to run unattended with a batch process. It must not allow to stop and ask for user input. If that happens, the batch process stays on hold indefinitely.

I cannot test the script for all the permutation of conditions that might cause user prompts.

Is there any way to force exception when any script stop and ask for user input?

Here is an example of code that could cause a user prompt. I know I can change this code to throw an exception. But this is one example of many, and at this point I rather not change all the code and find an alternate approach that fail the script when there is a prompt for user input like below:

```
function Show-Example
{
    param
    (
        [Parameter(Mandatory)]
        [ValidateNotNullOrEmpty()]
        [String]
        $Text
    )
    #Do something
}
```

Please note that in above code `[Parameter(Mandatory)]` will prompt user for input when the caller misses does not pass the parameter. I have several of this situation.

Comment: I don't know what your full constraints are, but you could just remove the mandatory attribute. Set `$text = $null`. Then in the script run `if (!$text) { throw "Missing parameter" }`.

Comment: @AdminOfThings, yes I know there are a few "code change" options do what you suggested, but that involves so many code changes in my framework. I am hoping to find options to have PowerShell crash and stop running as soon as any user input prompts.

Answer (score 0):

I'm having the same issue!

In my case I'm executing a .exe from powershell and I had to make it enter a new line on input request or disable input request from the executable script.